# SignalR not working on raspberry with windows 10

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, signalr, win-universal-app

The communication between my server and custom test client is working.

I add a connection from my UWP and run it on my local windows and it is working.

When i deployed my UWP on raspberry running win iot core the signal isn't received, no errors displayed in the output.

**Server:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
        // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
        // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
        // for more information.
        string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

**TestClient:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Set connection
        string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        var connection = new HubConnection(url);
        //Make proxy to hub based on hub name on server
        var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
        //Start connection

        connection.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            myHub.Invoke("SendSignal");
        }
    }
}
```

**UWP APP:**

```
InitializeComponent();

pushButtonValue = GpioPinValue.High;
InitGPIO();

//Set connection
string url = "http://localhost:8080";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
//Make proxy to hub based on hub name on server
var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");

//Start connection    
myHub.On("ReceiveSignal", FlipLED);
connection.Start();


//timer = new DispatcherTimer();
//timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
//timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
//timer.Start();
```

I have no idea what to check/do next.

Why isn't the message received when my app is running on my PI?

Comment: Packets can be captured at server side to see if the client does connect to it. Check that and post what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening to localhost on the Pi as well. Use the IP address or hostname of the server PC there to listen to that server as url.

---

If this is an answer to your question, please mark this as answer.

Comment: this was some part of the issue, i also changed on the server to my lan ip and in UWP app
then i also had to disable my firewall because the app on raspberry couldn't connect, this time some error was thrown, i will add a rule to my firewall.